# Linear Regression vs Ordinal logistic regression in this situation

Tags: r, ordered-logit

We're trying to examine whether certain variables about a medical student will predict how good of a program they will be accepted into in residency, and I need help figuring out our math:

**Our outcome variable**

We have information about what programs previous students were accepted into for residency.  This information is a 1-4 number that stands for the quartile of the ranking of that program.  I.e. a "1" is a top tier program in the top quartile.  A "4" is a bottom tier program.

**Our predictor variables**

We have variables such as:

- Was their med school a top 40 NIH funded school (yes/no)
- How many research manuscripts did they get published? (#)
- How many of those manuscripts were they first author on? (#)
- How many of their publications were in certain 'top' journals? (#)
- Was their medical school ALSO in that same quartile they landed in?  (y/n).   I.e. "yes" means they went to a "1" tier program and they were accepted into a "1" tier program.  "No" means that while they went to a "1", they were only accepted into a "3".

**Our goal**

Our goal is to determine whether the predictor variables we have actually predict the tier they'll be accepted into, and IF SO.... is there a variable that has the strongest effect?

**What I've tried so far**

So ultimately my question is: what specific type of regression is best (ordinal vs linear) but before I get to that point, I had done a bunch of univariate linear regressions for each predictor variable, treating the 1-4 "tier" outcome as a continuous variable.  Every single univariate regression was wildly significant.

I then did a multivariate regression (again, linear) and as you can see, some of the variables are no longer significant.  Makes sense to be honest, some of them were probably collinear (associated quartile residency and top40nihfunded both are determined by what school you went to).

Its at this point that I thought to myself, "hey, maybe this 1-4 tier is an ordinal variable.  We're not trying to predict if somebody is a 1.2 or 2.6 ... its only 1,2,3 or 4."

So at this point I tried a muliple ordinal logistic regression with this code:
[image]

**To summarize**

- Can/should the quartile level be treated as a continuous variable in a linear regression?  Granted its "levels", but unlike something like small, medium, large where the difference between small and medium might not be the same as medium to large....    these quartiles should be pretty consistent differences.

Comment: I'm not sure what you consider significant but not all of those pvalues are <0.05...6 of them are > 0.2

Comment: But also stop focusing on pvalues so much

Comment: @bdeonovic Haha good eye.  human error there. I saw scientific notation and assumed it was very small (like R does with the other regression results).  And your point about p values is noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinal regression seems appropriate here, but of course you have the additional assumptions to consider (proportional odds I think is standard?)

If you really wanted to stick to linear regression it might be more appropriate to treat it as censored data (ie you are trying to predict the rank of the program, but you only observe which quartile the rank is in).